# Ubuntu dual boot can't restart without battery charger but can boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, battery, restart

I just bought a new laptop Lenovo legion Y520 with pre-installed Windows 10 on SSD. I installed Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS on HDD.

I can do dual boot successfully by switching Intel RST (for Windows) to AHCI (for Ubuntu). I fixed the time difference issue following http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/dual-boot-fix-time-differences-between.html

I also fixed shutdown/restart freeze issue by using NVIDIA binary driver from proprietary in Software and Updates and editing /etc/default/grub to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=efi"
```

and finally run `update-grub`.

Everything works fine if the battery charger is plugged in. If it is not I can boot Ubuntu and Windows, however, Ubuntu cannot restart. I waited more than 5 minutes and nothing happened. Restart works for Windows 10.

I think I can discard battery dead issue since the laptop is new and both OS can be booted also with battery only.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: This reminds me of a PC which could not be shut down from Ubuntu 14.04. The only working SW way to shut it down were the commands from https://major.io/2009/01/29/linux-emergency-reboot-or-shutdown-with-magic-commands/. This problem was solved by moving to 16.04. So, could you try a newer Ubuntu version, namely 18.04, whether it hasn’t been fixed? The live session (Try Ubuntu without installing) should suffice to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to work on ubuntu 16.04 LTS